# What is the right way to export mongoose schema in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking at the example ([link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/models/Pet.js)) of mongoose with Next.js from official Next.js GitHub account. Here's the model that they have (I removed the comments):

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const PetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a name for this pet.'],
    maxlength: [60, 'Name cannot be more than 60 characters'],
  },
  owner_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please provide the pet owner's name"],
    maxlength: [60, "Owner's Name cannot be more than 60 characters"],
  },
  species: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please specify the species of your pet.'],
    maxlength: [40, 'Species specified cannot be more than 40 characters'],
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
  },
  poddy_trained: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  diet: {
    type: Array,
  },
  image_url: {
    required: [true, 'Please provide an image url for this pet.'],
    type: String,
  },
  likes: {
    type: Array,
  },
  dislikes: {
    type: Array,
  },
})

export default mongoose.models.Pet || mongoose.model('Pet', PetSchema)
```

Why do we export `mongoose.models.Pet || mongoose.model('Pet', PetSchema)`? Can we just export `export default mongoose.model('Pet', PetSchema)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of this pattern is to make sure that if you are working in a codebase where this module might be imported multiple times (which is common), you won't accidentally create multiple Mongoose models with the same name. Mongoose would throw an error if you try to create a model with a name that already exists.
It is a safeguard against potential issues that might arise from importing and exporting models across different parts of a codebase. However, if you are ABSOLUTELY certain that this module will only be imported once in your application, you can simplify the export statement to just export default mongoose.model('Pet', PetSchema).